# OpenLDAP backend failover

Tags: active-directory, openldap

I'm trying to configure OpenLDAP server as a proxy to Active Directory. And it works fine, but I cannot make openldap server to failover automatically without restarting slapd service. I have the following backend config in my slapd.conf

```
### Database definition (Proxy to AD) #########################################
database        ldap
suffix          "DC=***,DC=***"
uri             ldap://dc01:389,ldap://dc02:389
rebind-as-user
idassert-bind   bindmethod=simple
                binddn="CN=openldapro,***"
                credentials="***"
                mode=none
                starttls=yes
                tls_cacertdir=/etc/pki/tls/certs
                tls_reqcert=never
idassert-authzFrom "*"
overlay                 rwm
rwm-map                 attribute       uid             sAMAccountName
rwm-map                 objectClass     posixAccount    person
rwm-map                 attribute       homeDirectory   unixHomeDirectory
```

Even if I power off dc01, it's still trying to reach it. It fails over to dc02 only if I restart slapd. Is there any timeout value or anything else that have to be configured to make it work? Thanks.

Comment: will openldap work if dc01 and dc02 goes offline?

Comment: No it won't. That's just a proxy.

Answer (score 0):

You must use 'meta' backend instead of 'ldap' backend. Here is a sample configuration :

```
# Load dynamic modules
modulepath /usr/lib64/openldap
moduleload back_ldap
moduleload back_meta

# Database backend definition
database meta
suffix "dc=testdc,dc=local"
uri "ldaps://ldap1.testdc.local/dc=testdc,dc=local" "ldaps://ldap2.testdc.local"

lastmod       off
```